# Fixpoints of isometry is a totally geodesic submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry, geodesic

I'm working on the proof for:
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $F:M \rightarrow M$ isometry, $N:=\{x \in M \vert F(x)=x\}$. Now I want to show that $N$ is a totally geodesic submanifold.

I know that this question has already been asked and I also tried to understand the following proof for this: [image]

but as far as I see it, this only proofs that $N$ is a submanifold and not that it is totally geodesic. Is this part of the proof somehow trivial? (If yes, can somebody maybe explain it to me..?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll drop the * compared with your image.

A (unit-speed) geodesic in $M$ is uniquely specified by its starting point and a starting direction vector.  We start a geodesic at $p\in N$ and a direction $v\in H$.  The isometry fixes $(p,v)$ so fixes the geodesic.  So $\exp_p(B(0,r)\cap H)$ is fixed.

The only thing left to prove is that $H\supseteq T_pN$.  If $\gamma$ is a smooth curve on $N$ with $\gamma(0)=p$, then $\gamma$ is fixed, so $\gamma'(0)$ is invariant, so $T_pN\subseteq H$.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not really understand how this works, we want to show, that there is some neighborhood $U$ of $0$, s.t. for any geodesic $\gamma:I \rightarrow M$ it holds $\gamma(U) \subset N$ right?

Comment: @User1 by uniqueness of geodesic, $N$ is totally geodesic in $M$ iff every geodesic of $M$ that starts at point of $N$ parallel to $N$ stays on $N$.

Comment: I'm sorry if my questions are stupid, I'm a total beginner in differential geometry but what exactly does it mean that a geodesic is "parallel to $N$"?

Comment: I mean the geodesic's direction $\dot\gamma(0)$ is in $T_{\gamma(0)}N\subset T_{\gamma(0)} M$.

Comment: Ok, so do I understand correct: $\gamma'(0) \in T_{\gamma(0)}N $, $\gamma$ geodesic in $N$, then $\gamma'(0) \in H$ and therefore $\gamma(-\epsilon, \epsilon)=\exp_p((- \epsilon, \epsilon)\gamma'(0)) \in N$?

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure if I should start a new thread if I have another question? At first I thought that it's obvious, why $N$ is a submanifold, if $N\cap U \cong_{diffeo} H \cap W$ where $U$ is a neighborhood of $p$ and $W$ a neighborhood of zero in $T_pM$. But now I'm not that sure about it, I know that $H$ is an eigenspace of $dF_p$ for the eigenvalue $1$ and this is a subspace but can I follow from this, that $N$ is a submanifold?